# Why doesn't pdflatex compile my project?

Tags: miktex, koma-script

I want to compile a file, but pdflatex doesn't finish but gets in some endless loop. The only hint i have is from the Latex log, that it is something with the *koma-script\tocbasic.sty* file? This project worked perfectly yesterday. So I have no idea (atm) what could cause this? Some update? I completely reinstalled MikTex already. I am using Win 10.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.6)
entering extended mode
(f:/Dokumente/Masterarbeit.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01>
L3 programming layer <2021-06-01> HSMW-Thesis.cls
Document Class: HSMW-Thesis 2020/09/09
(C:\Users\Sandro\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty) (C:\Users\Sandro\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty (C:\Users\Sandro\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex (C:\Users\Sandro\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex (C:\Users\Sandro\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex)))) (C:\Users\Sandro\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(C:\Users\Sandro\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scrkbase.sty (C:\Users\Sandro\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scrbase.sty (C:\Users\Sandro\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlfile.sty (C:\Users\Sandro\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlfile-hook.sty (C:\Users\Sandro\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlogo.sty))))) (C:\Users\Sandro\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\tocbasic.sty)
```

Comment: you probably run into this bug: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/580.  A fix will be uploaded soon, but without small example it is difficult to give you the correct work around until this happens.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem compiling in `LuaLaTeX` (I am using a tempate that it is based on scrbook 2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script document class)